# Distinct and Count in query results

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a bit but can't quite figure this out.

I'm working with a table that has suppliers, projects, parts, shipdate, and arrivedate. I need to display with a single query the number of parts for each project that were delivered in 2017. So basically, I want it to display the ProjectNo in one column followed by the number of parts. I can run a query like this:

```
SELECT ProjectNo, PartNo
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE ArriveDate
BETWEEN 
TO_DATE ('1/1/17', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
AND 
TO_DATE ('1/1/18', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

And it will sort of give me what I need, but with duplicates in my ProjectNo column and obviously no count for PartNo. So I try the following instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectNo, COUNT(PartNo)
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE ArriveDate
BETWEEN 
TO_DATE ('1/1/17', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
AND 
TO_DATE ('1/1/18', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

And this just gives me a "not a single group function" error due to the COUNT function being used. How can I get the results I want, i.e.:

```
P1   |   3
P2   |   4
P3   |   7
```

and so on. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Remove `DISTINCT` as it has no meaning when you `GROUP BY` *something*, and you should `GROUP BY` values by column that isn't aggregated, and that's **PROJECTNO**.

```
SELECT ProjectNo, 
       COUNT(PartNo)
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE ArriveDate BETWEEN TO_DATE ('1/1/17', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
                     AND TO_DATE ('1/1/18', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY projectno;
```

**[EDIT]**

If you don't need `WHERE`, remove it. The rest should be OK:

```
SELECT PartNo, SUM(ArriveDate - ShipDate) AS Duration 
FROM SHIPMENTS 
GROUP BY PartNo
```

Comment: Thank you! Wish I could've figured this out on my own but very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Can I ask one more question - if I were to do a similar query but display an average number of days (i.e. ArriveDate - ShipDate) among all shipments? how would I do that? I'm trying a similar group by method but I don't necessarily need a WHERE statement in my query, so it isn't allowing me to group them together. e.g.: SELECT PartNo, SUM(ArriveDate - ShipDate) AS Duration
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE PartNo
GROUP BY PartNo

Comment: oh jeez I could've sworn I tried that and it gave me an error. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem; it happens :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ProjectNo, COUNT(PartNo)
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE ArriveDate
BETWEEN 
TO_DATE ('1/1/17', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
AND 
TO_DATE ('1/1/18', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
group by ProjectNO;
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple solution, shame I couldn't figure it out on my own hah.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the logic you want is:

```
SELECT ProjectNo, COUNT(PartNo)  -- use `COUNT(*)` if PARTNO is never NULL
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE ArriveDate >= DATE '2017-01-01' AND ArriveDate < DATE '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY ProjectNo;
```

Note that this does not use `BETWEEN`.  Presumably, you don't shipments that arrive on 2018-01-01.  Although written for SQL Server, Aaron Bertrand has a nice blog on why one should not use `BETWEEN` with date/times, 
[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Also, this uses the `DATE` keyword, allowing ISO-standard date constants.